# Navigae to a page in PageView from outside the page-view container widget

Tags: flutter

I have 3 pages (PageA, PageB & PageC) in pageView on the home page. I can switch between pages easily using a PageController. The 3 pages are also connected to BottomNavigationBar. I can also switch between pages via that.

Now, I have a problem:

How can I go to the PageB or PageC page in the PageView, from a page that is outside the home page?

Consider an example:

1. I go to PageA,
2. from there I go to a PageQ.
3. From PageQ, I tap the 2nd BottomNavBarItem for PageB. From here I am stuck.

If I try to navigate to HomePage, the PageA being initial page is displayed on the screen.

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: controller.pageController,
        children: [
          PageA(),
          PageB(),
          PageB(),
        ],
        onPageChanged: controller.slidePage,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavbar(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a logical problem rather than a technical one. Still answering so that anyone who faced such an issue could snap out of it.

PageView class works as intended. When you're navigating from another page that is not present in the PageView use `popUntil` instead of `push`. As `push` would create a new Home Page instead of the existing one!

```
  void redirectTo(int selectedPageIndex) async {
    if (Get.currentRoute != Routes.HOME) {
      Navigator.popUntil(Get.context, ModalRoute.withName(Routes.HOME));
    }
    pageController.jumpToPage(selectedPageIndex);
  }
```

Just pop until you're back to the home page and then jump to the desired index!

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to achieve a successful bottom navigation bar , you can try something like this :

```
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'presentation/screens/cart.dart';
import 'presentation/screens/home.dart';
import 'presentation/screens/order.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int page = 0;
  final _order = PageA();
  final _home = Pageb();
  final _cart = Pageq();
  Widget _showPage = PageA();
  Widget _pageChooser(page) {
    switch (page) {
      case 0:
        return Pageq();
        break;
      case 1:
        return Pageb();
        break;
      case 2:
        return Pageq();
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar( 
        elevation: 10.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[100],
        title: Image.asset("images/logo.png",scale: 14.0,),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        items: [
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label:"PageQ",
                icon:Icon(Icons.home)
            ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label:"PageB",
                icon:Icon(Icons.ac_unit)
            ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label:"PageA",
                icon:Icon(Icons.favorite)
            ),
        ],
         onTap: (index) async {
              setState(() {
                _showPage = _pageChooser(index);
              });
            },
      ),

      
      body: _showPage,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. In this case, I am not able to swipe to the next screen & the bottom-nav-bar is redrawn every time. A jerk is visible on the bottom-nav-bar when it is redrawn across pages. So, I want to keep it permanent. Sliding pages require PageView.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass that controller around which is probably a bad idea. A better way is to use `Navigator` You can even stick with `PageView` and pass a value to the constructor to set the initial page, but do think about redesigning. You may not need `PageView` maybe using separate pages with just `Navigator` to navigate is better. If I remember correctly page view can be useful if you need sequential steps, but don't limit yourself to it.

Comment: Thanks, bro! this is not because I need to but I want to. Like in the Whatsapp app I wanted to use PageView and use Navbar without redrawing it.